# Laravel not sending emails

Tags: php, laravel

I'm having trouble receiving e-mails using my mailtrap configuration in Laravel 5.6. I am using Laravels Auth system to reset password and everything is succesfull, but my mailtrap inbox is always empty. What am I doing wrong?
I tried playing around with different configurations, but no luck, I also ran config:cache, config:clear, cache:clear php artisan commands and restarted the server every time I changed the .env file.

[Laravel email sent](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eGWdq.png)

[mailtrap configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NH0kC.png)

.env file:

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.mailtrap.io
MAIL_PORT=2525
MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS=hello@example.com
MAIL_FROM_NAME=example
MAIL_USERNAME=XXXXXXXXXXXa4f
MAIL_PASSWORD=XXXXXXXXXXXa80c
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null
```

config/mail.php:

```
return [
'driver' => env('MAIL_DRIVER', 'smtp'),
'host' => env('MAIL_HOST', 'smtp.mailtrap.io'),
'port' => env('MAIL_PORT', 2525),
'from' => [
        'address' => env('MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS', 'hello@example.com'),
        'name' => env('MAIL_FROM_NAME', 'Example'),
    ],
'encryption' => env('MAIL_ENCRYPTION', 'tls'),
'username' => env('MAIL_USERNAME'),
'password' => env('MAIL_PASSWORD'),
'sendmail' => '/usr/sbin/sendmail -bs',
'markdown' => [
        'theme' => 'default',

        'paths' => [
            resource_path('views/vendor/mail'),
        ],
    ],

];
```

Comment: Have you checked the apache and php error log? This doesn't seem a laravel problem. Check also if the necessary php modules are enabled.

Comment: php error log not showing any errors, I "fixed" the problem by creating a fresh install of laravel and just restarting from scratch.